# Nodes look different

Tags: materials, node-editor

I assume that i touched some setting ,but i dont know what.

I use blender 2.79 now, and yesterday i was working on some material, doing some experiments. When i liked the result, i took a screenshot of the nodes:

[image]

Now i finished the modeling of one object and i wanted to make the same material for it, but when i went to the node editor, added a new material and nothing showed. Then i saw that there was "Use nodes" box and it was unchecked. I checked it and got this:

[image]

What was even weirder is that by changing the color from the material properties panell, i changed the color of it in solid view. My question is: How did i enable that and how to go back? If any further info is needed i will put it

Comment: You changed the render engine from cycles to blender internal.

Comment: @Carlo thanks, that fixed it!